# display data by ng-click and ui-router angular

Tags: angularjs

I have two page . Page one display data using ng-repeat call item.html , page two I show details of item , call details.html . Page one is ok , but page two have problem here is my code

item.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.mydata">
<a  ui-sref="details({param:data.masp})"                
                    ng-click="vm.details(data.masp)">
                    <td>{{data.masp}}</td></a>
</tr
```

here is my config route

```
 .state('details',{
                        url:'/details/{param}',

                        templateUrl:'/project/app/client/details/details.html',
                        controller:'shopController',
                        controllerAs:'vm'
                    })
```

here is my php

```
//connect db
    $data =array();
    $masp = isset($_POST['masp'])? trim($_POST['masp']) :'';
    $sql ="SELECT *FROM sanpham WHERE masp='$masp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $r['masp'] =$data['masp'];
    }
    print json_encode($data);
```

here is my controller

```
vm.details = function(ismasp){
                $http({
                    method :'POST',
                    url:'/project/app/server/action/details.php',
                    data:$.param({'masp':ismasp}),
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                }).then(success);

                function success(response){
                    vm.masp = response.data.masp;}
```

here is detail.html

```
{{vm.masp}}
```

but its not showing , where is my wrong . Pls help me . Thank in advance

Comment: try to remove anchor tag and put span plus use `$state.go('details', params)` so that on ng-click you can do it all

Comment: Check the ajax response there if you're getting success there and you're getting the expected response or not.

Comment: @JayantPatil thank for help , can you explain clealy , I should put it on somewhere?

Comment: You should not have a `ui-sref` **and** an `ng-click` on your anchor. It will probably go to the state without calling the `.details()` function

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng page one you have list of items on click of you have to pass its id to controller function then from there you have to redirect to details state using `$state.go();` as mentioned and then in shopcontroller you have details method so you will get state params to call api.

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng Or you can remove ng-click from anchor tag and use ui-sref only sothat will route to details/params and your controller will get that id from stateparams